# Android - view.post() not executed from getView() of BaseAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading, baseadapter

I have looked up and found out that `view.post()` won't work if you are calling it from thread other than UI thread and view is not attached to window. But I am calling it from UI thread, as you can see, and view is definitely attached but it is still not executing.

The most weird thing is that, it did execute in previous releases but for some reason it's not working anymore. There is no change in code from previous releases and current release.

Here is the code:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.m_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        /* A LOT OF OTHER CODE*/

        holder.itemView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("TAG", "POST EXECUTED");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `post()` returns a boolean. There is no `run()`

Comment: @BoradHardik you can't call `.run()` on `boolean` type. You are wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that your `/* A LOT OF OTHER CODE*/` does not contain `return`, which prevents your `post` code to execute?

Comment: no it does not contain any `return` statement

Comment: so adding a breakpoint on `post()` method and invoking a "step-in" action will show you whats wrong

Comment: It won't go in until I tap anywhere on activity

Comment: did you debug your code? can you perform "step in" action?

Comment: well it will execute on a different thread, so the "step-in" will take me to the next line `return convertView;`. But yes I have a debugger on `Log.d()` line and it won't fire until some UI change occur (touch, some image loading completed, etc.)

Comment: what different thread? `getView` is called in the UI thread, the `Runnamble` passed to  `post` method is executed in UI thread too

Comment: yes that is correct but after `holder.itemView.post(new Runnable() {});` line, it is `return convertView;`s turn to be executed, not `Log.d()`